# Is the inverse of a quotient map continuous?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I tried my best looking this up, but could not find anything. Very sorry if this is a duplicate.

We can define a quotient map $q:S^\infty \to \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ by identifying all antipodal points. We can possibly define an inverse to this map by choosing one of the two points. Can we choose the points in such a way that this inverse map is continuous, or does the structure of $\mathbb{R} P^\infty$ holds us back in creating such a continuous inverse?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean right or left inverse? Right doesn't exist by looking at homology, $S^\infty$ is contractible while $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ has a non-trivial homology. I'm not sure about left though.

Comment: I mean a map $i:\mathbb{R}P^\infty \to S^\infty$ such that $q\circ i = id$. Currently forgot if thats called a right or a left inverse.

Comment: That's a right inverse (it's on the right side of $q$).

Comment: @freakish A left inverse can’t exist since it isn’t injective. Unless you mean up to homotopy in which case any map will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no continuous $\mathbb{RP}^\infty\to S^\infty$ that is right-inverse to the quotient $S^\infty\to\mathbb{RP}^\infty$.

Indeed, it fails at the $1$-skeleton level already: there are no continuous $\sqrt{}$ on the unit circle $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How $S^1$ generalizes to whole $S^\infty$ exactly?

Comment: If you can't find a right inverse for $\mathbb{RP}^1\subset\mathbb{RP}^\infty$, you can't do it for $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$.

Comment: In fact a right inverse $r : \mathbb{RP}^\infty\to S^\infty$ has the property $r(\mathbb{RP}^1)  = r(q(S^1) \subset S^1$. Thus $r$ restrics to a right inverse for $q_1 : S^1 \to \mathbb{RP}^1$.